# memtest86+ exiting with process code 1 when running any sudo command in terminal

Tags: software-installation, dpkg, sudo

Hopefully this hasn't been posted before, I've already scoured the web in search of a solution to this.

I recently had to wipe and reinstall Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my drive partition. Afterwards, while installing packages via sudo apt-get, I started encountering a weird error at the bottom of the install.

At the very bottom of the install output:

````
 installed memtest86+ package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 memtest86+
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)```


A bit higher up, I get:

```pkg: error processing package memtest86+ (--configure):
 installed memtest86+ package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1```

```Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 memtest86+
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)```

It does not affect the install in any way though. It still works fine.

Is this a serious issue, and how can I fix it?
````